# how to dispaly index method in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am going to view My users table data (username,email) in index.blade.php file. I have UsersController.php like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Auth;
use App\User;

use App\Http\Requests;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
{
     $users = User::userr()->get();

    return view('users.index')->withUser($users);
}

}
```

My User Model is

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];





public function getAvatarUrl()
{
        return "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5(strtolower(trim($this->email))) . "?d=mm&s=40";
}

public function scopeUserr($query)
{
     return $query->where('username',Auth::user()->id);

}

}
```

and index.blade.php is

```
@if(isset($user))
@foreach($user as $use)
<h1>{ !! $use->username !! }</h1>
@endforeach
@endif

@endsection
```

routes is

```
Route::get('/index', function(){
    return view('users.index');
});
```

but when I visit index view is it display empty page (no error) and did not show name and email

how can fix this prob?

Comment: You don't have a method userr() in your user model.  Try $users = User::scopeUserr()->get();  Also you are sending variable users to the view and you are trying to loop through user.

Comment: I have userr() methos in My User Model. see it again...

Answer (score 0):

Use `User::all();` instead to get all datas from users table rather than `User::userr()->get();`

Also you have sent variable `$users` to your view and using `$user` in `@foreach` loop of blade.

Change `@if(isset($user))
@foreach($user as $use)`

to

`@if(isset($user))
@foreach($user as $use)`

on your blade file.Then it should work.

Comment: No, any solution on this way

Answer (score 0):

Check if your route has any action at the index (`/`). If not, set the route for the index to your desired view or controller. Then, from the controller, return the correct view along with the data you wish to send.

In the blade template, use the exact variable name you passed from the controller.

E.g. ,

```
Route::get('/', function(){
  //variable here
  return view('view')->with('var', $var);
});
```

In your blade,

```
@if(isset($var))
  @foreach($var as $use)
     //action here
  @endforeach
@endif
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Update your model and give a propper (meaningful) name to your scope

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function getAvatarUrl()
    {
         return "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5(strtolower(trim($this->email))) . "?d=mm&s=40";
    }

    public function scopeUsernameEmail($query)
    {
         return $query->select('username', 'email');
    }
}
```

Your controller gonna look like something like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Auth;
use App\User;

use App\Http\Requests;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
         return view('users.index', ['users' => User::query()->usernameEmail()->get()]);
    }
}
```

Then update your routes to use the controller method

```
Route::get('/index', 'UserController@index')->name('users.index');
```

And finally in your blade file loop over users like this

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td>Email</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if(isset($users))
            @foreach($users as $user)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $user->username }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    <tbody>
<table>
```